# dynamic execution of ghostscript

Tags: shell, variables, dynamic, ghostscript

I have the following command stored in a shell script variable.

```
x='gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output3.pdf /usr/share/ghostscript/8.70/lib/viewjpeg.ps -c "(PO-31649-1.jpg) viewJPEG showpage (PO-31649-2.jpg) viewJPEG showpage (PO-31649-3.jpg) viewJPEG showpage"'
```

When I execute the gs command directly on the command prompt, it creates output3.pdf.  However, when assign that command to a shell variable and execute the script, it errors out as follows:

GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

How do I execute a command stored in a variable?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for the links!!  That is exactly what I was looking for. The Eval command. Please mark this is as duplicate.

Comment: To be clear, `eval` is generally not the best/preferred/ideal way to do this. Depending on your goals, either a function or an array will generally be a better fit; the aforementioned FAQ will allow narrowing down which applies to the present case.

Comment: [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) goes into detail regarding why use of `eval` is generally considered bad practice.